# Drawing multiply images on a imshow window with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw 16 images side by side on a blank unnamed window. 
blank window size is 2456 x 1296 pixels. Each image size is 614x324 pixels. 
I want to know how to draw or display images together on one window. 
Here is my desired output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIe2b.png)

Comment: Copy them into one big image and show?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply concatenate 16 images into a big image by `cv2.hconcat` and `cv2.vconcat` functions like below.

```py
new_img = cv2.hconcat([im1, im2])
new_img = cv2.vconcat([im1, im2])
```